# with contain text selector in j query

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a solution for jQuery selector.

I have a table that contain `ID='svol-472, ID='svol-473......` and so on.

Here is my code. someone can help to modify my code.

I am looking for a selector that contain 'svol' text here is my code

```
function myFunction() {
    var svoltotal = 0
    $('#kwrdsTable > tbody  > tr').each(function(tr) {
        svoltotal += parseFloat($('#svol-472 span').text().replaceAll(',',''));                
    });
    console.log(svoltotal);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`I am looking for a selector that contain 'svol' text here is my code`
You can get the all td that has 'svol'

```
$('td[id*="svol"] span').text()
```

[Please referent this link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you.